# R crashes when loading dismo

Tags: r, rstudio

my first Q so be nice!

I am using R 3.1.2 in windows. All appear to load with no problems both either "library()" and "require()" except dismo. (v 1.0-5). When I try and load dismo R (and RStudio) freeze at this stage:

> library("dismo", lib.loc="~/R/win-library/3.1")
>   Loading required package: raster
>   Loading required package: sp

I get no further messages. R appears to be working but dismo never finishes loading.

I uninstalled and re-installed R, RStudio, dismo, sp, and raster but cannot fix this.

Any suggestions welcome,

Thanks

Comment: Exit RStudio. Fire up a non-GUI instance and retest. Then you will have a better idea where the problem lies.

Comment: Run  `library(sp)` and `library(raster)` to ensure you have those packages properly installed.